# Rust unpack iter of structs to iter of fields

Tags: rust, iterator

Assume I have a struct like this

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: f64,
    c: String,
    d: u8,
}
```

And `bar` is of type `Vec<Foo>`, which already contains many elements.

I would like to have three iterators of `Foo`'s first three fields (`a`, `b` and `c`) respectively. I know how to use `unzip` to achieve unpacking `bar` to its fields .

```rust
let (vec_a, (vec_b, vec_c)): (Vec<i32>, (Vec<f64>, Vec<String>)) = bar
    .iter()
    .map(|elem| (elem.a, (elem.b, elem.c)))
    .unzip();
```

But I don't know how to make iterators in ways alike.

```rust
let (iter_a, (iter_b, iter_c)): (
    Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>,
    (Box<dyn Iterator<Item = f64>>, Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>),
) = bar.iter().map(|elem| (elem.a, (elem.b, elem.c)));
```

This results in `error[E0308]: mismatched types`. Did I miss something or I just cannot use the syntax above at all.

Also as another question, `unzip` can only unzip pairs, if the struct has many fields, the nested level will soon explode, is there any better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply make three distinct iterators.

In the example below, the first part uses `.unzip()` as you did but fixes some errors.
`.iter()` prevents from consuming `elem.c`.
If we do not want to use `.into_iter()`, we need either a reference (`.as_str()`) or a clone (`.clone()`).

The second part simply makes three distinct iterators.
It's the solution I prefer, as stated in the first sentence.

The third part tries to keep your original idea: start from one iterator and expect to *split* it in three.
It could make sense if the process of obtaining the initial iterator was quite complicated and we didn't want to repeat it three times.
In this case, we have to clone the initial iterator itself and add a final `.map()` stage to each one.

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: f64,
    c: String,
    _d: u8,
}

fn show_iter<I, E>(
    title: &str,
    iter: I,
) where
    I: Iterator<Item = E>,
    E: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    print!("{}:", title);
    for e in iter {
        print!(" {:?}", e);
    }
    println!();
}

fn main() {
    let bar = vec![
        Foo {
            a: 1,
            b: 2.3,
            c: "X".to_owned(),
            _d: 4,
        },
        Foo {
            a: 2,
            b: 3.4,
            c: "Y".to_owned(),
            _d: 5,
        },
        Foo {
            a: 3,
            b: 4.5,
            c: "Z".to_owned(),
            _d: 6,
        },
    ];
    {
        // or use   vec_c: Vec<String>   and   elem.c.clone()
        let (vec_a, (vec_b, vec_c)): (Vec<i32>, (Vec<f64>, Vec<&str>)) = bar
            .iter()
            .map(|elem| (elem.a, (elem.b, elem.c.as_str())))
            .unzip();
        println!("vec_a: {:?}", vec_a);
        println!("vec_b: {:?}", vec_b);
        println!("vec_c: {:?}", vec_c);
    }
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    {
        let iter_a = bar.iter().map(|elem| elem.a);
        let iter_b = bar.iter().map(|elem| elem.b);
        // or use   elem.c.clone()
        let iter_c = bar.iter().map(|elem| elem.c.as_str());
        show_iter("iter_a", iter_a);
        show_iter("iter_b", iter_b);
        show_iter("iter_c", iter_c);
    }
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    {
        // or use   elem.c.clone()
        let iter_abc =
            bar.iter().map(|elem| (elem.a, elem.b, elem.c.as_str()));
        let iter_a = iter_abc.clone().map(|(a, _b, _c)| a);
        let iter_b = iter_abc.clone().map(|(_a, b, _c)| b);
        let iter_c = iter_abc.map(|(_a, _b, c)| c);
        show_iter("iter_abc iter_a", iter_a);
        show_iter("iter_abc iter_b", iter_b);
        show_iter("iter_abc iter_c", iter_c);
    }
}
/*
vec_a: [1, 2, 3]
vec_b: [2.3, 3.4, 4.5]
vec_c: ["X", "Y", "Z"]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iter_a: 1 2 3
iter_b: 2.3 3.4 4.5
iter_c: "X" "Y" "Z"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iter_abc iter_a: 1 2 3
iter_abc iter_b: 2.3 3.4 4.5
iter_abc iter_c: "X" "Y" "Z"
*/
```

Comment: In fact I used to make 3 iterators (if in this example) like you, I thought that's kinda redundant, there may exist some ways (like `unzip`) that I could use to simplify my codes, but I could not find useful posts on this. Is the overhead of cloning an iterator in rust something like copying some pointers, or much more than that?

Comment: @ElevenLee an iterator is *generally* something lightweight (a pair of integers, of pointers...) so that cloning it does not cost so much. Of course, one can always design an ad-hoc heavyweight iterator for a specific case, but this is not the primary intent.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I miss something or I just cannot use the syntax above at all.

The snippet just doesn't make any sense, `map` is a single iterator not 3, and it furthermore is not boxed.

> Also as another question, unzip can only unzip pairs, if the struct has many fields, the nested level will soon explode, is there any better way to achieve my goal?

https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.multiunzip.html should work for up to 12-uples.